# Cycle iterator in Swift

Tags: swift, iterator, cycle, swift3

In Python, there is [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which takes an `iterable` and makes an iterable iterator that repeatedly yields the contents from the source.

I would like to replicate this behavior in Swift.

A candidate for replicating this behavior would be the standard library's `repeatElement(_:count:)`: doing `repeatElement(seq, count: 5).flatMap({$0})` creates an array of the elements of `seq` five times, but this does not meet my requirements as it only repeats `seq` a finite number of times. Additionally, it creates an `Array` of length `5 * seq.length`, where only a cache of the length of `seq` is actually needed.

So the question is: how can I create an infinite `Sequence` by repeating the elements of a source `Sequence`? The solution should not have a space cost more than `O(n)`. (A `O(1)` would be impossible to guarantee in Swift, as a `Sequence` [makes no guarentee that it can be iterated multiple times](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence#2239542).)

Comment: FYI take a look at this implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46210298/3141234 It has an implied reliance on the wrapped sequences being reusable, but you can trivially wrap any one-shot sequence into an Array, and pass that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with manually implementing a `Sequence` backed by some array access modulo its length? With a bit of care your index need never overflow, and you can cycle on for as long as you like.

Note that the API docs warning reads more like a friendly reminder that re-use isn't a mandatory part of the `Sequence` interface contract. But that doesn't exclude your particular implementation from being reusable between multiple loops.