# The elegant solution for function that gives everytime called different element of array(ordered and starting from new when all returned)?

Tags: swift, swift4

I am a newbie and wonder what the elegant/Grown-up solution for my code would be.

I am also thankful for terms that I can look up related to this, seems like a common task.

*The "1,2,3"*  *are just placeholders so solution shouldn't rely on them being numbers*

```
var myValues = [1,2,3]
//function, that returns one element from array, in order, and starts 
//from beginning when all elements been returned once,twice etc.
func popper() -> Int {
     let returnValue = myValues.popLast()
     myValues.insert(returnValue!, at: 0)
     return returnValue!

popper() = 3
popper() = 2
popper() = 1
popper() = 3
...
```

it is not important that it starts with last, 1231231... would also be great!

edit: maybe more descriptive example:

I am having one clickbutton that changes a backgroundcolor from array of ["red","green","blue"]. So when clicking it multiple times the background turns red, turns green, turns blue, turns red ... not random and not ending.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What's the expected output, given the input `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: there is no input. It is declaration of array. if there was an input it would hae been declared in func.

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do. One sec

Comment: I had in my code a button, that sets a imageview(bool) to !imageview. I found that elegant and wondered how  something similar would look like for more than two states.

Comment: I see what you mean, but `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is definitely an input to what you're trying to do. You're just taking it via global variable access (bad!) rather than through a parameter or instance variable

Comment: ah ok. Yes I didn't know how to do differently because i need the array so it can store the info of the current state(after first call [4,1,2,3] , second [3,4,1,2] etc.)

Comment: So it's kind of unclear. Do you care about the values coming out of the `popper` function (as all the answers assumed), or do you care about this side effect it has, of shifting the array elements? If it's the latter case, you're probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153003/3141234

Comment: The first case is correct. I only shifted the array elements because so I could keep track of where I am in that array when the function gets called next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** The [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) package incorporates exactly this algorithm, under the name `Cycle<T>`. See https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Cycle.md

This process of "popping" is actually iteration... of a custom sequence.
The appropriate way of representing this in Swift is as a type (`struct`/`class`) that implements the `IteratorProtocol`. I called mine `CycleIterator` . Iterators are rarely used directly. Rather, they're usually provided by a type that conforms to `Sequence`. I called mine `CycleSequence`

The `Sequence` protocol simply requires the conforming type to provide a function, `makeIterator()`, which returns an iterator (`CycleIterator`  in my case). Simply by doing this, you instantly gain all of functionality of sequences. Iterability, `map`/`filter`/`reduce`, `prefix`, `suffix`, etc.

The `IteratorProtocol` simply requires that this type provide a function, `next()`, which yields returns a `Element?`. The return value is optional, as `nil` is used to represent the end of a sequence.

Here is how I would implement these:

```
public struct CycleSequence<C: Collection>: Sequence {
    public let cycledElements: C
    
    public init(cycling cycledElements: C) {
        self.cycledElements = cycledElements
    }
    
    public func makeIterator() -> CycleIterator<C> {
        return CycleIterator(cycling: cycledElements)
    }
}

public struct CycleIterator<C: Collection>: IteratorProtocol {
    public let cycledElements: C
    public private(set) var cycledElementIterator: C.Iterator
    
    public init(cycling cycledElements: C) {
        self.cycledElements = cycledElements
        self.cycledElementIterator = cycledElements.makeIterator()
    }
    
    public mutating func next() -> C.Iterator.Element? {
        if let next = cycledElementIterator.next() {
            return next
        } else {
            self.cycledElementIterator = cycledElements.makeIterator() // Cycle back again
            return cycledElementIterator.next()
        }
    }
}
```

```
let s1 = CycleSequence(cycling: [1, 2, 3]) // Works with arrays of numbers, as you would expect.
// Taking one element at a time, manually
var i1 = s1.makeIterator()
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(1)
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(2)
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(3)
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(1)
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(2)
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(3)
print(i1.next() as Any) // => Optional(1)

let s2 = CycleSequence(cycling: 2...5) // Works with any Collection. Ranges work!
// Taking the first 10 elements
print(Array(s2.prefix(10))) // => [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3]

let s3 = CycleSequence(cycling: "abc") // Strings are Collections, so those work, too!
s3.prefix(10).map{ "you can even map over me! \($0)" }.forEach{ print($0) }


print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: [true, false]).prefix(7))) // => [true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: 1...3).prefix(7))) // => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: "ABC").prefix(7))) // => ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A"]
print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: EmptyCollection<Int>()).prefix(7))) // => []
print(Array(zip(1...10, CycleSequence(cycling: "ABC")))) // => [(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "A"), (5, "B"), (6, "C"), (7, "A"), (8, "B"), (9, "C"), (10, "A")]
```

Here's a shorter, alternate implementation that shows how [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2011998-sequence) can be used to achieve a similar thing.

```
func makeCycleSequence<C: Collection>(for c: C) -> AnySequence<C.Iterator.Element> {
    return AnySequence(
        sequence(state: (elements: c, elementIterator: c.makeIterator()), next: { state in
            if let nextElement = state.elementIterator.next() {
                return nextElement
            }
            else {
                state.elementIterator = state.elements.makeIterator()
                return state.elementIterator.next()
            }
        })
    )
}
    
let repeater = makeCycleSequence(for: [1, 2, 3])
print(Array(repeater.prefix(10)))
```

Comment: Check out my answer. I don't know if that became possible sometime after you wrote this. I came here to see how other people had done it, and yours looked nearly identical. Great work! ⭐️

Comment: @Jessy Nope, that was always possible. There's a default implementation of `func makeIterator() -> Self { return self }` when `Self: IteratorProtocol & Sequence`. But it's kind of a trap if you accidentally use it with a `class`, because the iterator will be the same object as the base sequence, and iterating it would effect the base sequence, causing otherwise pure functions like `prefix` and `map` to be unpure.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're talking about a cycle function. It ties a finite sequence into a circular one, infinitely repeating the original sequence. You'll need lazy evaluation to pull this off.

```
public struct LazyCycleIterator <Base: Sequence>: IteratorProtocol {
  public typealias Element = Base.Element

  private var baseSequence: Base
  private var baseIterator: Base.Iterator

  internal init (_ baseSequence: Base) {
    self.baseSequence = baseSequence
    self.baseIterator = baseSequence.makeIterator()
  }

  public mutating func next () -> Element? {
    var next = self.baseIterator.next()

    if next == nil {
      self.baseIterator = self.baseSequence.makeIterator()
      next = self.baseIterator.next()
    }

    return next
  }
}

public struct LazyCycleSequence <Base: Sequence>: LazySequenceProtocol {
  public typealias Iterator = LazyCycleIterator<Base>

  private let iterator: Iterator

  internal init (_ baseSequence: Base) {
    self.iterator = Iterator(baseSequence)
  }

  public func makeIterator () -> Iterator {
    return self.iterator
  }
}

public extension Sequence {
  var cycle: LazyCycleSequence<Self> {
    return LazyCycleSequence(self)
  }
}
```

You would then call it like so on any `Sequence`:

```
print(Array([1, 2, 3].cycle.prefix(10)))
```

Or if you just want to keep getting the next value, do this:

```
var iterator = [1, 2, 3].cycle.makeIterator()

print(iterator.next()!) // 1
print(iterator.next()!) // 2
print(iterator.next()!) // 3
print(iterator.next()!) // 1
// Etc.
```

Comment: Your type doesn't actually conform to `LazySequenceProtocol`, because the variable "normally-eager operations such as map and filter" are not implemented lazily

Comment: [Are you sure?](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ba074b7eeaaa501aad1a1c)

Comment: Note that calling `makeIterator()` repeatedly on a *Sequence* does not guarantee that the elements are returned from the beginning, compare "Repeated Access" in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence. Only a *Collection* guarantees that.

Comment: @MartinR That's interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Definition:

```
struct CircularQueue<T> {

    private var array       : [T]
    private var iterator    : IndexingIterator<[T]>

    init(array: [T]) {
        self.array = array
        iterator = array.makeIterator()
    }

    mutating func pop() -> T? {

        guard !array.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextElement : T

        if let element = iterator.next() {

            nextElement = element
        }
        else {
            iterator = array.makeIterator()
            return pop() //Recursive
        }

        return nextElement
    }
}
```

## Invoking:

```
var queue1 = CircularQueue(array: Array(1...3))

print(queue1.pop())
print(queue1.pop())
print(queue1.pop())
print(queue1.pop())
print(queue1.pop())

var queue2 = CircularQueue(array: ["a", "b"])

print(queue2.pop())
print(queue2.pop())
print(queue2.pop())
print(queue2.pop())
print(queue2.pop())
```

Comment: If you just rename `pop()` into `makeIterator()`, you can conform to `IteratorProtocol`

Comment: I am new to custom iterators, `IteratorProtocol` seems pretty cool, your implementation more robust. Thanks for letting me know about `IteratorProtocol`

Comment: Yeah, they're pretty neat. Making this conform to `IteratorProtocol` means that you could have it be returned as the result of a `makeIterator` instance method of a type conforming to `Sequence` the result of that is that you can use map/filter/reduce, prefix, suffix, drop(while:), etc.

Comment: That's a lot of goodness to miss out on, definitely `IteratorProtocol` is the way to do it !

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer is awesome, but it can be simplified.

```swift
public struct CircularSequence<Iterator: IteratorProtocol>: Sequence {
  public init<Sequence: Swift.Sequence>(_ sequence: Sequence)
  where Sequence.Iterator == Iterator {
    makeIterator = sequence.makeIterator
    iterator = makeIterator()
  }

  private var iterator: Iterator
  private let makeIterator: () -> Iterator
}

//MARK: IteratorProtocol
extension CircularSequence: IteratorProtocol {
  public mutating func next() -> Iterator.Element? {
    if let next = iterator.next() {
      return next
    }
    else {
      iterator = makeIterator()
      return iterator.next()
    }
  }
}
```

You can always grab the iterator if you need it:

```swift
enum : CaseIterable { case , ,  }

let circularSequence = CircularSequence(.allCases)
let anySequence = AnySequence(cycling: .allCases)

func makePrefixArray<Sequence: Swift.Sequence>(_ sequence: Sequence) -> [Sequence.Element] {
  .init( sequence.prefix(5) )
}
let fiveBats = [., ., ., ., .]
XCTAssertEqual(makePrefixArray(circularSequence), fiveBats)
XCTAssertEqual(makePrefixArray(anySequence), fiveBats)

var circularSequenceIterator = circularSequence.makeIterator()
let anySequenceIterator = anySequence.makeIterator()
for _ in 1...(.allCases.count * 2 + 1) {
  _ = ( circularSequenceIterator.next(), anySequenceIterator.next() )
}
XCTAssertEqual(circularSequenceIterator.next(), .)
XCTAssertEqual(anySequenceIterator.next(), .)
```

```swift
public extension AnySequence {
  init<Sequence: Swift.Sequence>(cycling sequence: Sequence)
  where Sequence.Element == Element {
    self.init { [makeIterator = sequence.makeIterator] in
      Iterator( state: makeIterator() ) { iterator in
        if let next = iterator.next() {
          return next
        }
        else {
          iterator = makeIterator()
          return iterator.next()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension AnyIterator {
  /// Use when `AnyIterator` is required / `UnfoldSequence` can't be used.
  init<State>(
    state: State,
    _ getNext: @escaping (inout State) -> Element?
  ) {
    var state = state
    self.init { getNext(&state) }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but I'm not a fan of `let makeIterator: () -> Iterator`, because there's already a `makeIterator()` function. The name overlap is legal, but confusing. Also, that closure captures the full collection anyway, so I would rather just store the collection and call `makeIterator()` on it directly. That way the collection is available to access directly, such as for an implementation of `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: Reasonable opinions. But if not purely iterators, you should at least think of this as operating on sequences, not collections. Repeating a stride is a perfectly fun thing to do, for example.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that details. That's nice, IDR why i chose collection and not sequence. I think it was because *technically*, sequences aren't guaranteed to be repeatable. `UnfoldSequence` in particular is a class and its own iterator, it can't be repeated. Though I think that having edge cases like that is worth it to support `stride`